# Access Violation (no callstack) / Parallel.Foreach / GZipStream

Tags: c#, .net

I am going nuts with an Access Violation (attempt to read or write protected memory) that is being thrown without a call stack. I've done some searching and apparently this indicates the problem is occurring in unmanaged code.

With a bit of logging it seems to be occuring in a parallel foreach loop, where I am writing some files. This rang some bells because apparently GZipStream uses unmanaged code behind the scenes.

Can anybody spot any problems?

```
using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize<Document>(memStream, doc);

    using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(archive))
    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, false))
    {
         memStream.WriteTo(compressionStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you list contains the same filename twice?

Comment: This piece of code looks OK, although you don't need the MemoryStream. If the error is here then it has to do with the Parallel context.

Comment: @Jeroen: No I am not writing the same file twice

Comment: is possible you had dispose twice the compressedFileStream ? you are uses tow times "using statement", first time on compressedFileStream and second on compressionStream that contains the compressedFileStream.

Comment: How's the `Pararell.Foreach` being used? Can you add this to your code sample?

Comment: Is your serializer and `doc` thread-safe?

Comment: The Serializer *should* be thread safe, and from what I know it isn't calling any unmanaged code, so I don't know why I would get the access violation with no callstack from it. I'm going to move the serialization into another parallel loop, and see where it stops

Comment: It is technically possible to get access violations from pure managed code if you use threading and don't lock properly.  So an obvious way to get a better diagnostic is to get rid of the Parallel.For and try again.  Using the disk in more than one thread is a questionable practice anyway, you can have multiple processor cores but you still have only one disk.

Comment: @Hans, I never realized you could get an AV from pure managed code. When I remove the parallel loop I have no problems. I've inserted more logging into my code so that I can see exactly where the problem is occurring. Unfortunately it happens infrequently, so it's a waiting game. I am using multiple threads because I'm working with a large amount of very small files, which are on an SSD.